# How to change the image src in the map method when the image is clicked. React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a JSON file with some SVG images (3 purple, and 3 alt yellow SVGS). I'm importing the JSON file into my React Component. I'm mapping through a ids array to display the images, which works with no issue.

When I click one of the images in the map to change it to the purple version of the image, every image is changing, and not just the image I clicked, which is what I need.

I only want the image i clicked within the map method to change to the alt yellow image, and not all of the images.

Here's a look at my JSON file. the "unselected" are the purple image paths, and the "selected" are the yellow image paths

```json
// file.json
{
    "ids": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "label": "Happy",
      "unselected": "images/happy.svg",
      "selected": "images/yellow-wow.svg"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "label": "Shocked",
      "unselected": "images/shocked.svg",
      "selected": "images/yellow-wow.svg"
    },
    "3": {
      "id": "3",
      "label": "Sad",
      "unselected": "images/sad.svg",
      "selected": "images/yellow-wow.svg"
    }
  }
```

```
// component I'm importing the json file and mapping through images
// i'm passing handleSelection as a prop from App.js which currently just logs id
import React from 'react';
import Icons from "./file.json";

export const TempCheck = ({handleSelection}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
      Icons?.ids?.map(id => (
        <div className="icon-container" key={id?.id}>
          <img src={Icons?.[id]?.unselected} alt="" onClick={() => handleSelection(id)} />
          <p className="icon">{Icons?.[id]?.label}</p>
        </div>
      ))
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried passing a boolean from app, and using a ternary to change the src, but all images change. I can't figure out how to change the src only for the clicked svg image instead of changing all the svg images

Comment: What do you have in `handleSelection` ?

Comment: can you add screenshot on what is happening with code for `handleSelection`

Comment: handleSelection was just loggin the ID

const handleSelection = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  }

I was able to solve my issue looking at @atadurdyyewserdar codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an example for you. You will have to do small modification to your file.json.

Here is example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/exciting-euler-0uut11?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you so much! Looking at your codesandbox I was able to figure out my problem, and implement the solution into my actual app. You nailed it!